# Animate method didn't accept the width value with 'calc'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

When you click on the hide-menu button(green line), sidemenu hides and post wrap must change width to full size - but this does not happend.

I tried to set the width value through variable - the result, it works but without animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // HIDE-MENU BUTTON TOGGLE: full width of post wrap
  $('#hide-menu-btn').toggle(function(){
      var x = $('.post-wrap').css('width','calc(100% - 15px)');
      $('.post-wrap').animate({width:x},200);
    },function(){
      var y = $('.post-wrap').css('width','calc(100% - 135px)');
      $('.post-wrap').animate({width:y},200);
  });  
});
```

How can I animate post wrap width using animate method?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p4x4W/)